# Install GNU GMP on ubuntu after modifying its source code

Tags: gnu

I understand that installing GMP library on ubuntu requires 
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
My question is, since GNU GMP 6.1.2 source code files are publicly available over here (https://gmplib.org/) . I  want to tweak some values in the source code and then compile the code and use it in ubuntu 16.04 . Is there a way to do it ? If so, please can someone help me with that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/index.html) and especially part [3. Fixing a bug in Ubuntu](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/fixing-a-bug.html?highlight=debuild) .

All your steps in brief:

1. Clone source code of GMP for *xenial*
2. Make changes in its source code
3. Compile deb-package with your changes
4. Install your patched packages into system with `dpkg -i *.deb` or `apt-get install ./*.deb`.